# How to catch and accept specific action names in web api routing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

We are designing a web api and we want to catch all request towards our api and get action name and check if it's available in our database and if so,
a single method catch it.
actually the name of method should be customer bank account!
i know it seems odds but we were asked to do it in this way, say we have below request address

```
www.webSiteAddress.com/api/paya/123456789?amount=25&span=4587
```

`123456789` is our customer bank account that should act as action name!
 but first we should check it from the database
i came up with the solution below but it didn't work .

```
public class IBanRoutingConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        object IBan;
        values.TryGetValue("action", out IBan);
        if (IBan!=null && db.Accounts.Any(x=>x.AccountNo==IBan))
        {                
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and i used it as a constraint on web api routing.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
  config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "PayaApi",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
  constraints: new { action = new IBanRoutingConstraint() });
}
```

but i ended up with this message...

```
No action was found on the controller 'Paya' that matches the name '123456789'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found it my self...
for this situation i should go through two steps
first put a constraint on action in web api routing as below

```
public class IBanRoutingConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        object IBan;
        values.TryGetValue("action", out IBan);
        if (IBan!=null && db.Accounts.Any(x=>x.AccountNo==IBan))
        {                
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

then i need to inform to the api action selector how to deal with selecting action method during action selecting process

```
public class PayaActionSelector : ApiControllerActionSelector
{
    public override HttpActionDescriptor SelectAction(HttpControllerContext context)
    {
        var actionMethod = context.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType
         .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name=="Index");
        return new ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor(context.ControllerDescriptor, actionMethod);
    }
}
```

and api routing config would be like this

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
      config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "PayaApi",
      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
      constraints: new { action = new IBanRoutingConstraint() });
      config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpActionSelector),
                               new PayaActionSelector());
    }
}
```